# How do I know which QTcpSocket emitted the readyRead() signal?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qtcpsocket

I've created a hello-world program to help me understand how QTcpServer and QTcpSocket work. In it the QTcpServer accepts new connections and connects their `readyRead()` signal to the `MainWindow::onNewData()` slot where their new data is appended to a plain text control.

The problem is that multiple sockets can be opened simultaneously. So when I get the `readyRead()` signal and I want to read the data with `readAll()`, how do I know which socket emitted it?

Here's the relevant parts of the code. I'm not storing the QTcpSocket pointers at all here, but even if I did, I still wouldn't know which one of them emitted the signal.

```
    // constructor
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));
    server->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 3333);

void MainWindow::onNewConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket* socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), socket, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onNewData()));
}

void MainWindow::onNewData()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(WHICH_SOCKET_EMITTED_IT()->readAll());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way (as it seems to me) is to implement your own `Client` class which will encapsulate `QTcpSocket`

```
class Client : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Client(QTcpSocket *socket)
        : m_socket(socket)
{
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onNewData()));
}

private slots:
    void onNewData();

private:
    QTcpSocket *m_socket;
};
```

Easiest way: use `QObject::sender()` in slot function

Comment: Thanks, I used QObject::sender().

Comment: There is a rather old [example](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtservice/qtservice-example-server.html) by Trolltech which uses
`QTcpSocket* socket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();`
but I couldn't find this approach in newer examples. Are there any disadvantages/issues with this approach?

Comment: There are no disadvantages, except that you should never use C style casts in C++ code! Properly it's done as `QTcpSocket* socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender()); if (socket == 0) return;`

Answer (score 1):

Using a C++11 lambda functions in the connect statement, it's also possible to do this without the `sender()` function:

```
connect(socket, &QIODevice::readyRead,
        [this, socket()] { readData(socket) });
```

and a matching function (which does not need to be but can be a slot):

```
void foo::readData(QTcpSocket *socket)
{
    socket->whatever();
}
```